# Using BeiDou global short message communication services (BDS SMS)

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, gps, embedded

I want to use BeiDou Navigation Satellite System (BDS) in an embedded system (with Arduino or Raspberry Pi). In my preliminary research, I came to know that BeiDou has a global short message communication service. For my project, this feature can prove to be very useful. A 2019 [report](http://www.beidou.gov.cn/xt/gfxz/201912/P020191227430565455478.pdf) by the China Satellite navigation Office says,

> As for short message communication services in China and surrounding
> areas, the service capacity will be increased to 10 million times per
> hour and the receiver transmit power will be reduced to 1-3W, with
> capability as 1,000 Chinese characters per message (14,000 bytes). As
> for global short message communication services, the service
> capability is 40 Chinese characters per message (560 bytes).

This confirmed the SMS capability of the BeiDou system. Though [this document](http://www.beidou.gov.cn/xt/gfxz/201912/P020191227333024390305.pdf) mentions a *The User Guide Manual for BeiDou Navigation Satellite System Global Short Message Communication Service (Version 1.0)*, I could not find this manual anywhere (Maybe it is supposed to be issued in December 2020). And even after a long search session, I was unable to retrieve any useful information on using this specific feature. I worked with GPS modules before and am familiar with modules like [A9G Development Board](https://store.roboticsbd.com/arduino-bangladesh/1138-ai-thinker-a9g-gsmgprsgpsbds-development-board-robotics-bangladesh.html) or, [SIM7600](https://www.waveshare.com/product/sim7600e-lte-cat-1-hat.htm) that can use BeiDou alongside GPS. But I have seen no mention of *Global Short Message Communication Service (GSMC)* on those modules datasheet.

Now, is there any module that I can use with Arduino or Raspberry Pi to utilize the GSMC feature of BeiDou? Or any reference that I can follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vast majority of BeiDou modules have no Short Message capability. There are a few short message-capable modules available on Taobao. For example, [this](https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=576584639034), [this](https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=578321977613) and [this](https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=649784867472). Most of these modules use a serial interface like RS232, and a text-based protocol, so I think it wouldn't be difficult for them to work on Raspberry Pis. The cost is about a few hundred dollars. I can't find any on non-Chinese platforms.

The quote in your answer is a long-term forecast. Currently, most models have a capacity of 78 bytes per minute, with a subscription cost of about $15 per month.

Also, you need to be a Chinese citizen/have a Chinese ID to be able to sign up for the short message service. Not only that, a lot of the providers only do business with companies, not individuals. You might need to ask your Chinese friend for help.